# JDK file not found? (mac)

Tags: java

I downloaded a JDK from Oracle and try to put it into Unity's JDK path. I see posts that says you have to choose a path inside the JavaVirtualMachine. But I can't find anything in JavaVirtualMachine. I typed the command ***/usr/libexec/java_home*** in the terminal and it shows me this - ***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home***
It is suppose to be the path of the JDK. But as I mentioned above, I checked the finder and there is nothing inside the JavaVirtualMachine. Is there anything I am probably missing or done wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: P.S. I didn't download JRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Unity Hub and download/install the corresponding Android module to the Unity version you are using for your project.

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I actually only downloaded android build support but not **Android SDK and NDK tools** or **Open JDK**